# How to solve Error Use object destructuring prefer-destructuring - React

Tags: reactjs

I am stuck with an ugly issue which I am unable to resolve. I am beginner in React.

This is my Code

```
handleCheckChildElement(event) {
    let items = this.state.items;
    items.forEach(items = () => {
        if(items.value === event.target.value) {
            items.isChecked = event.target.checked;
        }
    });
    this.setState({ items });
}
```

This is the image of the error - [image: Error Image]

Comment: Please share the complete component code to understand better about the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be improved to something like below. Please find relevant comments in the code below for your better understanding

```
   handleCheckChildElement(event) {
           const { items } = this.state; //extract state values like this to a const variable 
           const newItems = items.map(item => { //do map on items because map returns a new array. It’s good practice to use .map than forEach in your case
                if(item.value === event.target.value) {
                         item.isChecked = event.target.checked;
                         return item; //return updated item object so that it will be pushed to the newItems array
                }
                return item; // return item because you need this item object as well
            });
           this.setState({ items: newItems}); //finally set newItems array into items
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for line #55 :

```
let {items}= {...this.state};
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Comment: Please wait, the errors are solved. I am trying to run the project.

Comment: I have seen that compilation errors are solved but let me run my  project in Chrome/Firefox. Please wait , I will definitely mark your answer correct in a short while

Comment: @Scooby what happened?

Answer (score 0):

```
handleCheckChildElement(event) {
   const items = this.state.items;
   const filtered = items.filter(item => item.value === event.target.value)
   .map(item => item.isChecked  = event.target.checked) ;
   this.setState({items : [...filtered] );
}
```

Comment: It would be super nice if you explain what you changed and why you changed. BTW, welcome to SO!

Comment: wt?! i wrote this for demonstration. how filter and change it  easily... in this example i replaced existing array with filtered result

Comment: @David: Even though you are replying a direct question. But it is always nice to write little explanation where questioner made mistake, how you've solved it.